# powerline doesn't work in ssh server on ubuntu

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, powerline-plugin

I am using these command to open my ubuntu(18.10) server

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo apt install net-tools
sshd
ifconfig
```

and then I use the terminal on other device(termux on my android phone) to connect the server by IPadress, but the powerline of my ubuntu doesn't work(the style of the commandline shows in default on termux).
I can make sure it is not the problem of `powerline`, because when I using ubuntu to connect other ssh device, the powerline worked correctly and the installation steps and configurations are all the same between two devices. The command of opening ssh server on the other device is

```
pkg install openssh
sshd
ifconfig
```

which is almost the same as my ubuntu. I don't know why my devices work differently. How to let the powerline on my ubuntu work correctly?

Comment: Hello, I couldn't understood - what is *powerline*?

Comment: https://github.com/powerline/powerline/blob/develop/README.rst